# what is the meaning of "$a->{$1}" in perl

Tags: perl

I was wondering what is the exact meaning of "->" in perl. It is said it is a dereference operator. So can anyone explain it more clearly?
Thanks.

Comment: accessing elements of an hash reference

Answer (score 0):

When you have a hash, it's something like:

```
my %hash = ( "a" => "123", "b" => "256" );
```

and then you reference elements using `$hash{"a"}` notation.

But in some cases you might want to have reference to hash, and not hash itself.

This can be done in many ways, like:

```
my $reference = \%hash;
```

or

```
my $hash_ref = { "a" => "123", "b" => "256" };
```

When you have hash reference in variable, you have to dereference it before getting value. This is where -> operator comes in, like:

```
$hash_ref->{"a"}
```